# Signed APK crashes on Runtime while Unsigned APK doesn't (Proguard)

Tags: android, binding, proguard

I've been facing this problem for weeks now and I still can't get it to work.
First of all I am using data binding for my project and it all runs smoothly without any runtime crashes using Android Studio's ADB. Even when I generated a signed "debug" APK for testing, it runs smoothly as well, until I set minifyEnabled to "true" on the debug and exported the APK (debug) out and it crashes. 
So, I'm pretty sure there's something to do with Proguard optimising my classes / files.

Here is my app module :

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

So, to sum it up. When I change the debug's "minifyEnabled" to "false" and export the APK and test it on my phone, it runs fine.
But when I change it to "true", it crashes on runtime.

I've already added '-keep class' and '-dontwarn' in my proguard file.
Here it is :

```
-dontwarn android.databinding.**
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class android.databinding.annotationprocessor.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.viewmodel.**
-keep class android.viewmodel.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }

-keep class java.lang.** { *; }
```

My project runs Crashlytics and I've seen the error of the crash, which points to the databinding class. But I've already told proguard to keep the class as stated above.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, this is the error I'm getting from Crashlytics :

```
com.myproject.android.databinding.ItemProductDataBinding.executeBindings (Unknown Source)
```

How do I know which class Proguard is helping to optimise and which class isn't? Hope you guys have the answer, and save me another few weeks of headaches. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you tried adding those lines to your proguard config? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/a53fdf4a28693a8ebbc5d3fef1e44423a560dc90/proguard.cfg

Comment: Can't find the proguard config file, but I've read another post and they said the config file is actually the proguard.pro file

Comment: Yes, you should add those lines in the `proguard-rules.pro` file in your folder. But that was the easy part as it is indicated in the app build.gradle `proguardFiles` line